# Tableau/SQL Calculated Field With Grouping

Tags: sql, group-by, tableau-api

I have a table with the following structure

```
id, event_name, event_date
| 1 | a | 1.1.2020 | 
| 2 | b | 3.2.2020 | 
| 3 | b | 3.2.2020 |
| 3 | b | 5.2.2020| 
| 1 | b | 31.12.2019 | 
| 2 | a | 5.1.2020 |
```

My goal would be to perform a grouping on the id and then I'd have to check wheter the date of an event 'a' comes before an event 'b'. If so I'd like to output 'ok' and 'error' elsewise.

In this example this would result to

```
id, check
| 1 | error| 
| 2 | ok |  
| 3 | ok |
```

Would it be possible to perform the task with a calculated field in Tableau? **SQL would be also be ok!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   Select id, case when diff<0 then 'ok' 
   else 'error' end as status from 
   (
    Select id,

    max(case when event_name ='a' then event_date end) - 
    max(case when event_name='b' then event_date end)
   As diff
    From table group by id order by id)
```

Comment: That's smart! What if I'd have the event_names a, b, c and I'd have to additionaly check if the value b is in a group. if not, output 'missing value', instead of error for example

Comment: Yes, you would have to in that case you could make use of a  `lag() or a lead() ` function thats a straightaway usecase for the same.

Comment: @Himashu Ahuja unfortunately I can't figure out, how to incorporate lag() or lead() to make it work. Could you add it to your answer? I'll edit my question then

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query with UNION clause:

```
select id, 'Error' "check" from mydata md where event_name='a' and id in 
(select id from mydata where id=md.id and md.event_name<>event_name 
and md.event_date > event_date) 
union
select id, 'Ok' "check" from mydata md where event_name='a' and id in 
(select id from mydata where id=md.id and md.event_name<>event_name 
and md.event_date < event_date);
```

Output should be :

```
| ID | 'ERROR' |
|----|---------|
|  1 |   Error |
|  2 |      Ok |
```

ID=3 doesn't appear, because event_name both are 'b'.

Comment: That's a cool approach! Unfortunately the runtime with union would be very slow in my case

Comment: Can you try to build index (composite index) on the table for the 2 columns EVENT_NAME and EVENT_DATE?